# Finding HTTP Post parameters in IIS logs preferably using Splunk

Tags: iis, splunk

I am able to find the GET parameters that are made as part of a request but I am not able to retrieve the POST parameters for a request. Can you guys tell me what should be my search parameters for the same?

Does IIS actually log this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

IIS does not log POST parameters. POST is commonly used for large data sets and file uploads which would take up a ton of space on your disk and could cause your server to run out of space easily.

You can setup some manual logging with something like log4net and log POST parameters. File growth will still be a problem but log4net can be configured to limit growth and roll-over at a certain size. You can then index your log4net logs using splunk